Firebase and Stripe integration - Stripe doesn't show my metadata on invoice.paid()
I am trying to integrate stripe on my SaaS. I have been stuck for the last 3 days trying to send unique userID metadata to stripe. my UUID doesn't show on invoice.paid() hence i can't tell which unique user has made the payment.

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { userId, priceId } = req.body;

    try {
      console.log('Creating session for Firebase UID:', userId);

      // Fetch the user from Firestore
      const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(userId).get();
      if (!userDoc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
      }
      const userData = { uid: userDoc.id, ...userDoc.data() };

      // Create a checkout session
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [{ price: priceId, quantity: 1 }],
        mode: 'subscription',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/canceled`,
        client_reference_id: userId,
        customer_email: userData.email,
        metadata: { 
          firebaseUID: userId,
          userEmail: userData.email,
          subscriptionType: 'Pro'
        },
        subscription_data: {
          metadata: { 
            firebaseUID: userId,
            userEmail: userData.email,
            subscriptionType: 'Pro'
          }
        }
      });

      console.log('Checkout session created:', session.id);
      res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating checkout session:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
};

It seems like I am sending the metadata to stripe, but it doesn't show up on any of the stripe logs. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Would appreciate any advice/suggestion here.

The metadata you are sending is, I'm guessing, what you are passing in the subscription_data parameter. If that is the case, then you are just looking in the wrong spot.  The metadata you are adding is being set on the Subscription object.  This does not automatically copy to the Invoice object, which is what is returned in the invoice.paid event.  Stripe documents the few scenarios where metadata is copied between related objects here.
If you want to get the metadata as part of your handling of the invoice.paid event, you will need to retrieve the Subscription object using the ID that can be found in the invoice.subscription property.
